# Odd version of 24 squares formula?

Tags: spheres, integer-lattices

The Leech lattice is related to the formula:

$$1^2+2^2+3^2+....+24^2=70^2$$

This is related in turn to 26D bosonic string theory.

Is there another known formula that involves the integers 1..8, which is related perhaps to $E_8$ or 10D supergravity?
At first I thought it might be the sums of squares of the first 8 odd numbers but this didn't give anything interesting. (Because supersymmetry includes half spin particles $1/2,3/2,5/2$ etc.

(The Leech lattice and $E_8$ being the lattices with maximal sphere packing in their respective dimensions).

Edit: I found another examples. Not sure if they have any relevance:
$$2^2+5^2+8^2+11^2+14^2+17^2+20^2+23^2+26^2=48^2$$
Which goes up in 3's and also this is 9 terms. Probably just a coincidence.

Comment: Check the eight squares identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degen%27s_eight-square_identity and this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651080/models-for-lie-algebra-e8-and-octonions

Comment: Interesting. This makes me wonder if there is a 24-square identity!

Comment: There is the Pfister 16 square identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfister%27s_sixteen-square_identity and a free paper on the 2-, 4-, and 8-square identities https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfister%27s_sixteen-square_identity. I do not know of a 24-square identity.